# Get the connection name of the failed step in ssis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have this ssis package and in it, an OnError event handler. When the package fails, I enter data into an error log table. How (if possible) does one get the connection of the step that failed? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: "the connection" is very vague - exactly what are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Event Handler you could use the value of the variable - System::SourceName. If your components are named sensibly then this value would let you know the component that failed and hence the connection.